# Array of composite type as class data members in ExtJS

Tags: arrays, class, extjs, extjs4, composite

I'm new to ExtJS and am trying to replicate a typical Java class in ExtJS.
Take the following as example:

```
class A {
    B b[];
    C c[];
}

class B {
}

class C {
}
```

I searched but didn't find anything on 'composite arrays'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something I don't understand but I don't think you need to declare the type of the members.

```
A: {
    b: [],
    c: []
},
B: {
},
C: {
}

//...

var myClass = new A();
myClass.b.push(new B());
```

Comment: I've tried this, can you please tell me whats wrong?
http://pastebin.com/N0cKeuf1